# Render 3D maps comprising of buildings and other structure using OpenLayers-Cesium (ol-Cesium) can anyone me from where can i begin?

Tags: openlayers-3, cesiumjs, 3d-mapping

I am trying to render 3D maps comprising of buildings and other structure using OpenLayers-Cesium (ol-Cesium) does anyone know how to do it or from where can i begin?